# May You Use a Predicative Complement in Front of I Feel, I, Subject, Feel, Copular Verb?

Tags: syntax, predicative-complement, linking-verbs

> Badness, I feel.
>
> Badness, feel I.
>
> Bad, I feel.

May you grammatically use a predicative complement in front of *feel* (copular verb)?

Comment: For unusual rhetorical effect, yes; otherwise no. ... And if you run across *I feel badness*, you may be assured that *feel* is not being used as a copular but as a verb of sensation or perception.

Comment: @StoneyB Many grammars consider verbs of sensation to be copula. In general, in English adjectives follow copular verbs. On the other hand, adverbs are movable, which is what I think is confusing the OP here.

Comment: *Feel* certainly has a copular use (*I feel bad*, *I feel sick*), but with a noun complement (*I feel badness*, *I feel sickness*) the noun is pretty clearly a direct object, not a predicative.

Comment: Interesting. I guess, an object complement gets something done to it. So, badness gets felt? So, grammatically, you may feel badness in you, or not in you? *I feel badness*., and *Badness I feel.*, grammatically, cannot get used having *feel* as a copula? I guess nouns don’t get used after copular verbs? I don’t think I can get a difference in meaning, of *I feel nauseous.*, from *I feel nausea.*.

Comment: May this mean one can solely, grammatically, use *Badness, feel I.* as an imperative *Badness, feel me.*?